# Java Generics in arguments

Tags: java, generics

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IRadioButtonGroup<T> {
 List<IRadioButton<T>> getButtons();
}
```

Now I create a method

```
protected Object getDefaultRadioButtonValue(IRadioButtonGroup<?> field) {
List<IRadioButton<?>> buttons = field.getButtons();
```

Now java is complaining:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<IRadioButton<capture#1-of ?>> to List<IRadioButton<?>>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unbounded wildcard parameter type of your method means that, it will accept an `IRadioButtonGroup` of an unknown type. The compiler doesn't know what type will come, but at compilation time, the compiler does generate and assign each wildcards with a placeholder, because although it doesn't know which type is coming, it is sure that there has to be a single type that will replace `?`. And that placeholder is `capture#1-of ?` you see in the error message.

Basically, you are trying to assign a `List<IRadioButton<Cap#1-of-?>>` to a `List<IRadioButton<?>>`, and that is not valid, in a similar way how `List<List<String>>` cannot be assigned to `List<List<?>>`.

One well known way to solve these issues is to use **capture helpers**. Basically you create a generic method, and delegate the call to that method. That generic method will infer the type parameter and then you would be able to do type safe operation. See [this Brian Goetz's article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html?ca=drs) for more details.

So to solve the issue, provide another method as in below code:

```
protected Object getDefaultRadioButtonValue(IRadioButtonGroup<?> field) {       
    return getDefaultRadioButtonValueHelper(field);
}

private <T> Object getDefaultRadioButtonValueHelper(IRadioButtonGroup<T> field) {
    List<IRadioButton<T>> buttons = field.getButtons();
    // Write the logic of original method here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<IRadioButton<?>> buttons = new List<IRadioButton<?>>();

foreach(IRadioButton button in field.getButtons())
{
 buttons.Add(button);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
protected <T> Object getDefaultRadioButtonValue(IRadioButtonGroup<T> field) {
    List<IRadioButton<T>> buttons = field.getButtons();
    return buttons;
}
```

or

```
protected Object getDefaultRadioButtonValue(IRadioButtonGroup<?> field) {
    return field.getButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
protected Object getDefaultRadioButtonValue(IRadioButtonGroup<?> field) { List<IRadioButton<?>> buttons = field.getButtons();
```

to:

```
protected Object getDefaultRadioButtonValue(IRadioButtonGroup<IRadioButton<?>> field) {
```

List> buttons = field.getButtons();